# less.js has no method 'toCSS' on watch

Tags: javascript, less

I am using less.js (version 1.2.1) on localhost (on Windows), and when I use `less.watch()` in console, I keep getting this error:

```
less.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLinkElement> has no method 'toCSS'
```

I searched for an answer to solve this, but no luck. Anyway on how to fix this error? The less.watch() does work, but it also is slow and every second I get that error.

Anyway to fix this?

There is really nothing in the html, here is how I set up less though. Am I doing it wrong?

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/styles.less">

<script src="js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Firebug Console:

```
b.toCSS is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

b && r(b.toCSS(), d, e.lastModified)
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using on http://jsfiddle.com ?

Comment: I'm not using any code. Once I set less.watch() in console, the error appears. I'll post how I set up less though.

Comment: D'oh! Obviously. Hmm… That is weird. What happens if you remove all the content from the `<body>` of your page — does it still happen?

Comment: yup. I found this https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/575 but I can't find the part where he said to change. I am using the current version which is 1.2.1 minified (I can't seem to find a dev version or unminified version)

Comment: Ah, weird. Not a great fix, but maybe it would work with Firefox?

Comment: No, didn't work. But got a different error then one in Chrome.

Comment: I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLinkElement> has no method 'toCSS'" with version 1.2.1 in Chrome on Linux. The watch works, but has this error. In Firefox, the watch works without an error.

Comment: I used the [unpacked version](https://raw.github.com/cloudhead/less.js/master/dist/less-1.2.1.js) and found an error on [line 2981](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/dist/less-1.2.1.js#L2981), but it looks like [souldreamer](https://github.com/souldreamer) found [a solution](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/575#issuecomment-3738493).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dev version is at https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/dist/less-1.2.1.js

The relevant section is:

```
if (less.env === 'development') {
    less.optimization = 0;

    if (/!watch/.test(location.hash)) {
        less.watch();
    }
    less.watchTimer = setInterval(function () {
        if (less.watchMode) {
            loadStyleSheets(function (e, root, _, sheet, env) {
                if (root) {
                    createCSS(root.toCSS(), sheet, env.lastModified);
                }
            });
        }
    }, less.poll);
} else {
    less.optimization = 3;
}
```

In the section:

```
if (root) {
    createCSS(root.toCSS(), sheet, env.lastModified);
}
```

Change:

```
if (root) {
```

to:

```
if (root && sheet) {
```

then re-minify (if desired) and use the new file.